# how to getElementByID() when the id is a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, getelementbyid

For example:

```
<?php  foreach($something as $anotherthing){  ?>
    <span id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>"><?php echo $price; ?></span>

    <?php if($option == 'select') { ?>
    <select name="joe" id="<?php echo $select_id; ?>" > ......
```

I have no idea how to get the id's into javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML is text. JavaScript is text. So - the same way.

```
getElementById('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');
```

Comment: @James — No, it only works if the JS is generated from PHP. It doesn't have to be inline. (Although you need to be trickier with how you assign `$product_id` in the two different PHP scripts if you split it into multiple files).

Answer (score 2):

The same way as in HTML :

```
document.getElementByID('<?php echo $id?>');
```

Comment: String literals require quoting in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that :)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion, either use `$_SESSION` or put the variable into a hidden input field that always has the same name, then you can get the value from there and use it as the ID :)

Answer (score 1):

Given you use a syntax similar to `product-N` or `product[N]` if you only have a want all products on the page:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=product]');
```

if you want just one of those you can use only the first match add `[0]` just before the `;`